# In One Night Werewolf: Monster, does the master play?

Tags: one-night-werewolf, one-night-werewolf-monster

I got the ruleset for [One Night Werewolf:Monsters](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/185350/one-night-werewolf-monster) and it mentions that it can be played with 3-7 players.
However, I don't think it is clear if the Master is also a player or just narrates the game and does not actually play?

Comment: Note that there are apps that can handle giving the instructions

Comment: That is a nice thing to know! I will look for such app that is PT-BR friendly

Comment: I didn't notice the "Monster" part of the game name, so I won't confirm there's one for your specific game. Still, something worth looking for :)

Comment: I went to a boardgame related website that is in PT-BR and there is an audio of the turn orders there. I would never even think about that if you hasn't suggested it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All play. You don't need a master: the players can all call the time/sequence (with their heads down and eyes closed) as needed. If you have a spare "player" who wants to moderate, that's fine, too, of course.